# Why does my Firebase Phone Authentification code not work?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I copied and modified some code snippets to make a user authentificate via phone number.
The first time that I entered my phone number, I got sent a code and everything worked just fine.
However, any future attempts did not work at all.

I already entered the SHA-1 code and the package name is correct too.

```
String verificationId;
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

/// Sends the code to the specified phone number.
  Future<void> _sendCodeToPhoneNumber() async {
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (AuthCredential user) {
      setState(() {
          print('Inside _sendCodeToPhoneNumber: signInWithPhoneNumber auto succeeded: $user');
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (AuthException authException) {
      setState(() {
        print('Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}');}
        );
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
      print("code sent to " + "$vorwahl$handynummer");
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
      print("time out");
    };

     await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '$vorwahl$handynummer',
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }
```

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 4243): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@b0b2b7f
I/FirebaseAuth( 4243): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth( 4243): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
I/HwSecImmHelper( 4243): mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/flutter ( 4243): Phone number verification failed. Code: firebaseAuth. Message: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]
```

Comment: Is it possible you have added debug `SHA1' testing in release mode?

Comment: The error shows what you are doing wrong: `This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console`